# Howto automate webview facebook login with appium

Tags: android, node.js, appium

I´m trying to write an appium functional test in node.js. 
The problem comes when I switch to the webdrivers context.

Here are my contexts:

```
[ 'NATIVE_APP', 'WEBVIEW_com.******.***.development' ]
```

This is the test case code:

```
   "use strict";

    var wd = require("wd");

    require('colors');
    var chai = require("chai");
    var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
    chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
    var should = chai.should();
    chaiAsPromised.transferPromiseness = wd.transferPromiseness;

    var wd = require("wd");

    describe("android simple", function () {
        this.timeout(300000);
        var driver;
        var allPassed = true;

        before(function () {
            driver = wd.promiseChainRemote({
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 4723
        });

        driver.on('status', function (info) {
            console.log(info.cyan);
        });
        driver.on('command', function (meth, path, data) {
            console.log(' > ' + meth.yellow, path.grey, data || '');
        });
        driver.on('http', function (meth, path, data) {
            console.log(' > ' + meth.magenta, path, (data || '').grey);
        });

        var desired = {
            'browserName': '',
            'appium-version': '1.3',
            'platformName': 'Android',
            'platformVersion': '4.4.2',
            'deviceName': 'Android Emulator',
            'app': "path/to/apk"
        };

        return driver
            .init(desired)
            .setImplicitWaitTimeout(3000);
    });

    after(function () {
        return driver
            .quit()
            .finally(function () {
                if (process.env.SAUCE) {
                    return driver.sauceJobStatus(allPassed);
                }
            });
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        allPassed = allPassed && this.currentTest.state === 'passed';
    });

    it("should find facebook login button", function () {

        return driver
            .elementById('facebook_login_button')
            .click()
            .sleep(10000)
            .contexts()
            .then(function (ctxs) {
                console.log(ctxs);
                return driver.context(ctxs[ctxs.length - 1]);
            })
           .elementByName('email')
           .sendKeys('test.*****@gmail.com')
           .sleep(5000)
           ;
    });
});
```

And the output error from appium server:

error: Chromedriver: Error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Original error: unknown error: Device emulator-5554 is not online
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64))
    at JWProxy.command$ (lib/proxy.js:149:15)
    at tryCatch 
status: 13,
  value: { message: 'unknown error: Device emulator-5554 is not online\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64)' },
  httpCode: 200 }

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you are setting browser capabilities? It seems that its an issue with chrome driver that comes with Appium. Try opening default browser by setting `capabilities.SetCapability("browserName", "Browser");`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I added the browser settings are they ok?

Comment: Yup fine. Just try putting `browserName` as `Browser` instead of blank. See if at least it is opening default browser. [Appium discussion](https://discuss.appium.io/t/difficulty-with-browser-chromium-on-android-emulator-and-chromedriver/1017)

Comment: I tried but it doesn´t work. Gonna add the full test

Comment: Ohh...you mean points from above link also did not help? In that case, sorry I may not be able to resolve. :(

Comment: Nope, my problem seems to be the context change. When i execute return driver.context(ctxs[ctxs.length - 1]); the appium server throws an error. Thanks anyway for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. It just was a chromedriver bug. Updated to version 2.20 and everything works fine.

Github issue:
https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/5616

Chromedriver release notes:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Answer (score 1):

Try different android device, issue is with adb returning extra characters with device name. See
https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/5686

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I´ve tried with both, different android emulator and changing 'deviceName': 'Android Emulator' but it doesn´t work, throwing the same error. Did I miss something? Thanks again.